# Unable match exact symbols "&" "<" ">" using xpath coding

Tags: xpath

I have to find the exact symbols `&`, `<`, and `>` present within the XML comment tag:

```
<!--Q1: find & < > symbols--> ..
```

I have used the code `//comment()[matches(.,'[\&|\<|\>]')]` and it's not working.. do not use hexadecimal value to find this scenario.

I have to convert UTF8 XML files into named entity XML files. UtF8 xml will have these symbols like in format & < >. However after conversion named entity XML file will have these symbols like in the format & amp; & lt; & gt;. I have to use two different xpath condition in both XML files.. In named entity XML the xpath code //comment()[matches(.,'[& amp;& lt;& gt;]')] is enough to find & symbol in any format like & amp;, &x38; (& will be automatically converted as & amp; so no & symbol in XML file) in the XML file.. Suppose if user inserted utf8 symbol "&" in named entity file wrongly during correction means I have to find and highlight only "&" not "& amp;", "&#38:".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text in HTML comment using XPath and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859155/extract-text-in-html-comment-using-xpath-and-regex)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does xpath remove html special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897523/why-does-xpath-remove-html-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xslt, the code itself is encoded in XML. Therefore, you need to escape the symbols properly:

```
//comment()[matches(.,'[&amp;&lt;&gt;]')]
```

In most other languages, no escaping is needed at all

```
//comment()[matches(.,'[&<>]')]
```

Comment: I have to find and highlight UTF8 character symbols & < > so named entity and hexadecimal values should not be used to find in xpath code

Comment: You haven't understood the answer (which is correct). You want an XPath expression that contains the characters `&`, `<`, `>`. To write such an expression in an XML environment such as XSLT, you write them as `&amp;`, etc. On the other hand, if the XPath expression appears in a Java string literal, they don't need escaping. (You need to clarify where this XPath expression is being written).